# rails path issue when calling for generators

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, path

I am running `rails` app and inside `myapp/lib/`, I have `./generators/test/test_generator.rb` file with

```
class TestGenerator < Rails::Generators::Base
...
```

I get this message when running `rails` server :

/home/myapp/lib/generators/test/test_generator.rb:1:in `': uninitialized constant Generators::NamedBase (NameError)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add

```
require 'rails/generators'
```

at the top of your file

Comment: This does work, but it's unclear why it's needed. The Rails docs don't mention needing the explicit require, and the generator generators don't have them. Color me confused.